# c# WPF Update Window on Button Click

Tags: c#, wpf

I have been messing around with c# in Visual Studio (rather new to it) and have been trying to build an application using WPF and I cannot seem to figure out how in my environment to update my WPF view when a button is clicked. I have tried to cull my code down to the relevant information

I have the following scenario in my .cs file

```
class Program
{

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        try
        {
            using (VMS.TPS.Common.Model.API.Application app = VMS.TPS.Common.Model.API.Application.CreateApplication("null", "null"))
            {
                Execute(app);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());

        }
    }


    static void Execute(VMS.TPS.Common.Model.API.Application app)
    {
        Window window = new Window();
        MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow(app);
        mainWindow.evalButton.Click += Eval_Click //Button defined in .xaml

        //Add a bunch of items

        window.ShowDialog();
    }
    public static void Eval_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //need to add some more stuff to mainWindow and update window
    }
}
```

My MainWindow.xaml file has class defined as .MainWindow and the MainWindow.xaml.cs file is as follows

```
public partial class MainWindow : UserControl
{

    private VMS.TPS.Common.Model.API.Application _application;

    public MainWindow(VMS.TPS.Common.Model.API.Application Application)
    {
        _application = Application;


        InitializeComponent();

    }

}
```

Comment: What does "Update my WPF view" mean in this context?

Comment: Maybe that is phrased incorrectly. Perhaps append the new xaml elements to the existing window or close the existing window and throw window.ShowDialog() again. The window vie just needs to be updated with the new elements.

Comment: How are you "adding a bunch of items"? Are you adding to your "MainWindow" which is in fact a UserControl?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `View` layer to update on button press, you can re-assign the `DataContext`. For example:

```
public static void Eval_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.DataContext = new MyDataContext();
}
```

But if you're following the MVVM pattern, your `DataContext` should inherit from the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and you can also just call a `PropertyChangedEventHandler` event to update specific bindings in the `View` layer. For example:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;  
private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")  
{  
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
public void UpdateView()
{
    NotifyPropertyChanged("foo");
    NotifyPropertyChanged("bar");
}
```

...

```
public static void Eval_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (this.DataContext as MyDataContext).UpdateView();
}
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work but this is probably my technical abilities. I manages a solution by declaring window and mainwindow as global items and then could access their context in the eval click function. Probably not the best solution but got it working.